# How to change UPDATES and INFO folers between each other (change their places between each other)?

Tags: socialengine

How to change UPDATES and INFO folers between each other in SocialEngine profiles? I need INFO folder of user profile data to be before his UPDATES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this needed in engine4_core_content table change between content_id columns 540 and 541 their values for order column like this: content_id|541 = order|1 and content_id|540 = order|2.